# MySQL(Joomla) - Unknown Column

Tags: mysql, joomla

I've migrated my one component from one of my website to another. They are in same version and everything looks fine except two errors that I've listed below.

```
Unknown column 'a.downloads' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT a.*,c.cid AS category, c.name AS category_name 
FROM ve63d_joomgallery AS a LEFT JOIN ve63d_joomgallery_catg AS c ON c.cid = a.catid 
WHERE a.published = 1 AND a.approved = 1 AND a.downloads > 0 ORDER BY a.downloads desc LIMIT 0, 5
```

the other one is :

```
 Unknown column 'c.password' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT c.cid, c.parent_id, c.name, c.access, c.published, c.hidden, c.owner
 FROM ve63d_joomgallery_catg AS c WHERE lft > 0 AND c.published = 1 AND c.access IN (1,1) AND (c.password = '' OR c.cid IN (0)) ORDER BY c.lft
```

How can I fix these tables?

Comment: You should write down table's schema, it looks like some columns are missing as the error states

Comment: I like this one **IN (1,1)** :-)

Comment: Thank you @Fabio ! I could managed to list column structure and create the needed ones and it looks perfect.